# how to capture image in android phone using application

Tags: selenium, appium, appium-android

I have to automate the script where i will click on the camera icon in my application which will open the camera but am not able to capture the image and attach the image.

I am using Appium and i tried these two possibilities:

1)`oBrowser.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.KEYCODE_CAMERA);`

2)`oBrowser.pressKeyCode(27);`

But none of them works.
Can any one help me to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C adb shell input keyevent " + eventNumber);